# How to assign values to all records in a group

Tags: sql

Let's say I have fields `x` and `y` and `x` might contain multiple instances of the same value. For all values in `x` which are the same, I want to construct that many new values, using the values of `y` which correspond to those `x` values. E.g., let's let the new field be called `z`:

```
id    x    y    z
 1    3.5  17   f(17, 9, 11)
 2    3.8  12   f(12, 2)
 3    3.5   9   f(17, 9, 11)
 4    3.5  11   f(17, 9, 11)
 5    4.2   7   f(7)
 6    3.8   2   f(12, 2)
 7    2.1  13   f(13)
```

This is something like a GROUP BY clause, but instead of collapsing the group into a single record, I'd like to keep separate the individual records which went into it.

The function `f` which is applied is going to be just the average of the `y` values, if it makes it any simpler. But I wonder if it's possible to formulate such a query in greater generality.

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSI standard SQL supports window functions, so this can be done as:

```
select t.*,
       avg(y) over (partition by x) as z
from t;
```

Most databases support these functions.

Answer (score 0):

Window functions are just the right thing, but some implementations (e.g. MySQL) don't support them. For the record, here's a workaround which works for MySQL:

```
select t.*, u.z 
  from t, (select x, avg(y) as z from t group by x) as u
  where u.x=t.x;
```